# How to filter() interactively a DT by choosing a criterion in a selectInput() and defining the a numericValue()

Tags: filter, shiny, dplyr, shinydashboard

I'm triying to create a shiny app that allow users to filter a data table by choosing a numeric variable in a selectInput() and a numeric value in a numericValue(). 
I'm getting erros, whatever I tried

I tried to call a variable in the server function using four ways (input$y, get(input$y), !!get(input$y), !!sym(input$y)), without getting the expected result.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$filteredtable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      newtab <- movies %>%
        dplyr::filter(!!sym(input$y) < !!sym(input$numValue))

      DT::datatable(data = newtab)
    })
  })
```

I am expecting that the table reacts interactively to the seledcted Input and the defined numeric value.

`input$y` --> gives an empty table that doesn't interact with what we choose in the selectInput()

`get(input$y)` --> gives the `error: invalid first argument`.

`!!get(input$y)` --> gives the `error: object 'runtime' not found` ('runtime' is a numeric variable from the used file).

`!!sym(input$y)` --> gives the `error: Only strings can be converted to symbols`

Comment: Could you provide your ui as well to get to know your input values?

Comment: ui is above. Data are from http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4850/datasets/movies.Rdata

Answer (score 0):

For sure @Thomas Fuchs

```
ui <- shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(), 
        dashboardSidebar(

          # Critère du filtre 
            selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                        label = "Choisir ici le critère du filtre : ", 
                        choices = c("runtime", "thtr_rel_day", "dvd_rel_year","critics_score", "audience_score"),
                        selected = "runtime"), 

          # Slider 
            numericInput(inputId = "numValue", 
                        label = "Choisir une valeur numérique pour le filtre", 
                        value ="500", 
                        min = 1, 
                        max = 1000,
                        step = 50, 
                        width = '100%')
        ), 

        # body 
        dashboardBody(
          fluidPage(
            box(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "filteredtable"), 
                title = "Les données filtrées")
          )
        )
    )
  )
```